# Ecommerce app design - relation between order and cart

Tags: database-design

I found many design for ecommerce app where there is a separation between *order* and *cart*
where order table has 1*n to order_item and order_item 1*1 to product
and same goes for cart - cart_item - product

Isn't it easier to relate order table with cart items ?
[image: Text]
reference : https://fabric.inc/blog/shopping-cart-database-design

Answer (score 1):

My understanding here is that the cart and order are two completely separate entities. A cart can be updated, with items added/removed/quantity modified. These items are what's displayed in the front end. An order is final and is created when the user pays.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally their would be no relation between order and cart. User can place multiple items in cart but he may or mayn't place order of all the items. these are 2 separate entities and we have to make entries when cart items moved to purchase(in online payment) or confirm order (in case of COD), then we have to store all these items in order table.